# Como somar uma Coluna de dados no R Studio?

Tags: r, programação-funcional

tenho uma coluna com 31 dados, referentes a 31 dias. Trabalhando com temperatura máxima daquele dia. Preciso somar a coluna 6 referente ao meu banco de dados, mas não sei como executar. Abaixo seguem os valores.

```
##criação do objeto TempMax
TempMax <- (tasd[,6])
TempMax

##todos os dados expostos
 [1] 294.8990 294.6704 294.3795 294.1463 293.9750 293.8162 293.6966 292.5143 292.9038 292.6970 292.3918 292.4655 293.0239
[14] 293.1961 294.7348 292.8138 294.3303 294.7993 294.8764 294.4225 293.7932 293.1985 292.3853 291.6981 291.0097 291.9837
[27] 295.6363 296.4483 296.8291 296.7959 296.6817
```

---

## Dados

Basta copiar e colar.

```
TempMax <-
c(294.899, 294.6704, 294.3795, 294.1463, 293.975, 293.8162, 293.6966, 
292.5143, 292.9038, 292.697, 292.3918, 292.4655, 293.0239, 293.1961, 
294.7348, 292.8138, 294.3303, 294.7993, 294.8764, 294.4225, 293.7932, 
293.1985, 292.3853, 291.6981, 291.0097, 291.9837, 295.6363, 296.4483, 
296.8291, 296.7959, 296.6817)
```

Comment: `sum(tasd[,6])` ou `sum(TempMax)`?

Comment: O resultado é `[1] 9111.212`, já agora.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Para somar os valores da coluna 6, basta usar a `função sum()` e passar o vetor `TempMax` como argumento:

```
soma_temp_max <- sum(TempMax)
```